# How to make Enter on a CheckBox and MVPDatePicker act as TAB button

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want the Enter Key to behave as the TAB key. Therefore I've been using the keyDown event with the following code:

```
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            SelectNextControl(ActiveControl, true, true, true, true);
        }
```

or

```
     if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
        }
```

However, whenever I encounter a CheckBox or a MVPDatePicker control, the focus got lost and pressing enter doesn't do anything anymore. I had to press TAB to unlock the situation.

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this problem?

Comment: I think you have define something first on the PreviewKeyDown event of the checkbox (I assumed you are referring to the KeyDown event of the checkbox). 

May i know your objective or specific action expected when you press the enter?

Comment: Yes I am refering to the KeyDown Event. My objective is to simply act as the TAB key, to go to the next active control. For exemple I have a TextBox->CheckBox->TextBox. Starting from the first TextBox, pressing Enter would leadi me to get the focus on the CheckBox, and when I am here I lose the focus and pressing enter again doesn't do anything.

Comment: Do you lose the focus on the checkbox instantly? Even without pressing or clicking anything? I think the reason why pressing the enter once again does not work anymore is because the 'ENTER" function is define only at your checkbox KeyDown event and since the focus is no longer in that object, it is calling the KeyDown event of the current object it is focusing.

Comment: Yes I lose focus as soon as I press enter and arrive on the checkbox. But I've set the Key Down Event to all the controls on this form.

Comment: Have you checked the TabIndex of all the controls in the forms? In your given scenario, your 1st Textbox should have the TabIndex of 1, while the Checkbox should have TabIndex of 2 so that when you press the tab, it will focus on the objects carrying the next tabindex value. Also ensure that the TabStop property for all the objects are set to True